# Upgrading google-services:1.0.3-beta1 to 1.5.0-beta2 causes "libpng error: Read Error"

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, build.gradle

While working with Google Analytics I was required to upgrade my version of google-services to 1.5.0-beta2. So the dependency in my project level build.gradle now reads:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

Upon doing so I now get the following error when compiling:

```
AAPT err(Facade for 1720657): libpng error: Read Error
```

Compiling with --stacktrace gives the following:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeCustomerDebugResources'.                                                                                                                                  
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)                                                                                                            AB, maven2, maven3]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)                                                                                                                   
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)                                                                                                     
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)                                                                                                                       
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)                                                                                                                           
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)                                                                                                       
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)                                                                                                             
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)                                                                                                                           
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)                                                                                                             
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)                                                                                                         
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)                                                                                                         
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:62)                                                                                                         
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)                                                                                                                 
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)                                                                                                                           
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)                                                                                                                                        
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details                                                                                                                                                     
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher.waitForAll(QueuedCruncher.java:260)                                                                                                                                                       
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher.end(QueuedCruncher.java:280)                                                                                                                                                              
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:132)                                                                                                                                              
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:291)                                                                                                                                                            
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:48)                                                                                                                                                     
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:174)                                                                                                                                          
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:104)                                                                                                                                     
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)                                                                                                                                                                
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)                                                                            
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)                                                                                 
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)                                                                              
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)                                                                                 
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)                                                                                                             
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)                                                                                                            
    ... 14 more
```

If I revert to the previous version the build works fine.

Likewise, in the same file I am using gradle 1.3.0:
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

If I upgrade this to 1.5.0 along with google-services, or independently, I get the same error

Comment: Have you tried restarting your Android Studio?

Comment: Yep. I've restarted Android Studio, invalidated cache etc, and have tried running gradlew directly. The problem still exists

Comment: You can try to invalid the caches: Go to File --> Invalid Caches. And then rebuild: Go to `Build` --> `Clean project` --> `Rebuild preject`.

Comment: tried that also. I've now updated to google-sevices version 2.0.0-alpha3 and gradle 1.5.0, and the problem has gone